# I've got a Germany 'visitor/business' visa with 12 days left after my trip.

Tags: visas, schengen

So the visitor visa lasts for 30 days 
and I only stayed in Germany for 18 days 
Will I be able to plan my next tourist trip to France without applying for a tourist visa ?

Comment: When does the current visa expire? And is it a single-entry or multiple-entry visa?

Comment: Although there are some details missing, it's clear what's being asked, and possible to give an answer which covers both possibilities of the missing details, as demonstrated by the two (similar) existing answers.

Answer (score 3):

Schengen visas are a 'use or lose' document...

On the expiry date of your visa all unspent leave is automatically depleted; so your 12 days will be forfeit when that happens.

You also forfeit any unspent leave if your visa is 'single entry' and you exit the zone.

Returning to your question:  Yes, you can visit France and use your 12 unspent  days if...

1. Your Schengen is marked as multiple entry; and
2. Your Schengen's expiry date is still in the future.

If both of those conditions are true, you simply need to be out of the zone before the visa expires.  If either of those conditions are false, then your visa is no longer useful.  Hopefully you included France in your itinerary when you applied, otherwise you will need to think up a plausible explanation when you clear immigration controls in France.